# Background image animation not working in Firefox

Tags: css, animation, background

Background image animation not working in Firefox and I don't want the background repeat image in animation.

Here is url: http://trekoholic.com/site/

```
body {
    background:url(../img/bg.jpg);
    -webkit-animation: slide 30s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0%{ background-position: left 20%; }
    25%{ background-position: 100px 0; }
    50%{ background-position: 200px 0; }
    100%{ background-position: 300px 0; }
  }

@-moz-keyframes slide {
    0%{ background-position: left 20%; }
    25%{ background-position: 100px 0; }
    50%{ background-position: 200px 0; }
    100%{ background-position: 300px 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line:

```
body{
 background:url(../img/bg.jpg);
-webkit-animation: slide 30s linear infinite;
animation: slide 30s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Dariusz Majchrzak but I dont need my image repeat what wolud be solution for that.

Comment: body {background-repeat:no-repeat}

Comment: body {background-repeat:no-repeat}  have tried already but the problem is image is not cover the whole screen :( @ Dariusz Majchrzak